# TIMEDIFF() function in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, datetime, time

Is there any PHP function that does the same thing as SQL function TIMEDIFF() ?

Here is my code:

```
$to_time = array_search( 'time2.Time', $aCols );
$from_time = array_search( 'time1.Time', $aCols );
$value= ;
```

I need to get values in this format `HH:MM:SS`

I use this version :  PHP 5.2.17

Comment: what format are `$to_time` and `$from_time` in?

Comment: they are in this format `'2012-09-13 12:15:07.562'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use php 5.3 or after you can use the following code

```
$to_time = new DateTime(array_search( 'time2.Time', $aCols ));
$from_time = new DateTime(array_search( 'time1.Time', $aCols ));
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
$value = $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

or before 5.3 try something like this:

```
$date1 = strtotime("2012-09-13 12:14:24.453");
$date2 = strtotime("2012-09-15 14:21:28.453");
$interval = $date2 - $date1;
$seconds = $interval % 60;
$minutes = floor(($interval % 3600) / 60);
$hours = floor($interval / 3600);
echo $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/b9b0L5

Comment: this is not working for me... because I'm getting only `07:00:00` values for all the records which is not correct. How to make this work? I know that your example is working but I don't know what should I do

Comment: maybe the difference is bigger than 24 hours. in this case you have to  add the day/month/year to the $value

Comment: when I tried this `"y:m:d h:i:s"` I am getting this values: `69:12:31 07:00:00` and `time2=2012-09-13 12:21:21.406` and `time1=2012-09-13 12:14:24.453` this is really strange

Comment: I'm getting `0:0:0` as output

Comment: Nothing really. I have everything as you got it. Maybe the problem is in the format? Time is saved as varchar in the table?

Comment: That schouldn't be a problem. maybe you can paste the dates you get out of the db into the codepad. if you don't get an error there then it must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes I managed it to work. I had a column problem. Your code is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$dattTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime2 = new DateTime("2012-09-11 10:25:00");


$interval = $dattTime->diff($dateTime2);
var_dump($interval->format('%H:%i:%s'));



$hours = $interval->h + ($interval->d*24);
var_dump("Total Hours: " . $hours . " hrs");
```

Output

```
string '08:17:15' (length=8)
string 'Total Hours: 608 hrs' (length=20)
```

Comment: @denonth i just delayed the time so that you can see the diff .. i can update with better example

Comment: this is really great example but I need to achieve this with `PHP 5.2.17`

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` if needed to convert the values to timestamps (which they should already be ideally) and then just subtact the two.

Comment: `$timeSinceMidnight = time()-strtotime("midnight");`

Answer (score 0):

Get your time in "H:i:s"  format, keep a start date as 00:00:00 its easy by strtotime()

```
   <?php
    $origin   = '00:00:00';
    $fromTime = '00:16:00'; // $fromTime = date('H:i:s',strtotime($from_time))
    $toTime = '00:45:00';  //// $toTime= date('H:i:s',strtotime($to_time))

    $diff = (strtotime($toTime) - strtotime($fromTime)) + strtotime($origin);

    echo date('H:i:s', $diff );
```

output : 00:29:00